# How to keep PartnerUser in sync with PartnerContact

Tags: community, partner-communities

I have an requirement where a partner admin (User with Partner profile) should be able to make user from their Contacts .  In addition , partner will update their contacts and  user related to those contacts should be updated automatically.  There is requirement to keep partner contact and user in Sync.

I have tried but there is no "manage external user" permission on Community profile. Is there any way to keep partner contact to sync in with Partner user without a trigger. Thanks.

Regards
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Without a trigger, another option would be to add some logic to the updateUser() method in your registration handler to update the contact when that user logs into the community. The only time that the contact would get updated is when the user exercises the reg handler though (logging in).

Another non-trigger option is a scheduled batch.